# Why are both products observed due to Molecular Orbital theory

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

I can reason out the first product as the highest occupied orbital of one excited molecule is approached by the lowest unoccupied orbital of the ground state molecule. I cannot rationalize the second product; am I missing an aspect of MO bonding that is important?

Comment: Simply turn one of them around.

Comment: Oh, wow, that clears it up.

Comment: This is probably worth buffing up into a full answer, @Mithoron